# UIAppearanceProxy background image bugs

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiappearance

I'm using UIAppearance selectors for UIToolBar, UINavigationController, UISegmentedControl, UIBarButtonItem etc. and I'm seeing some REALLY strange behavior occasionally.

Somehow it's almost like the UIControls reset themselves after certain actions.  Here's a screenshot of what I mean.  Basically it's as if they no longer have the images.  If I click on the controls or rotate to reset them, they'll eventually reset but I have no idea what's causing this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image]